# Firefox does not spellcheck

Tags: firefox, spell-check

I have a strange Problem, despite spellchecking being active (I checked via settings, there I put `Check my spelling as I type` to `enabled` and checked `about:config`, `layout.spellcheckDefault` is set to `1`, I tried `2` as well - [see here](https://www.technipages.com/firefox-enabledisable-spell-checker)) and several languages installed the spellcheck does not work and there is no option to choose the language via context menu.

I checked on the same fields with other browsers, it works fine...
(My goal is to find out why this is not working, I know I could use a work around like Grammarly, but feel free to suggest workarounds anyway, I guess other people with similar problems might benefit).

Is there some setting I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, it was a simple problem, once I knew what I was looking for. The language and dictonaries downloads for Firefox are (currently) on the same webpage. Instead of downloading the dictionary I didn't realize I was downloading the language pack (once you scroll down and don't see the headline anymore).

[image]